# Why doesn't this Haskell code compile?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to calculate a list of factors for a number in Haskell. This is my current code:

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = map floor [x | x <- [2..sqrt n], n `mod` (floor x) == 0]
```

However, when I try to run it, it throws off this error:

```
largestprimefactor.hs:4:17:
No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `floor'
In the first argument of `map', namely `floor'
In the expression:
  map floor [x | x <- [2 .. sqrt n], n `mod` (floor x) == 0]
In an equation for `factors':
    factors n
      = map floor [x | x <- [2 .. sqrt n], n `mod` (floor x) == 0]

largestprimefactor.hs:4:37:
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `sqrt'
In the expression: sqrt n
In the expression: [2 .. sqrt n]
In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [2 .. sqrt n]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm trying to learn Haskell, so it is probably just a dumb beginner mistake, but I've tried to fix this for hours and can't find an answer.

Comment: your function's (`factors n = ...`) type signature `factors :: Int -> [Int]` says that its argument is an `Int`, i.e. `n :: Int`; then you use `[2..sqrt n]` but `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a` says `n`'s type must be in `Floating` typeclass. Yet `Int` is not in `Floating` (try `Prelude> :i Int` at GHCi prompt). *That* is what the second error message is telling you.

Comment: so to fix it, write `.... sqrt (fromIntegral n) ...`.